# While checking vector size i get: 'Expression: vector subscript out of range'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vector

I have function that from vector of doubles (representing polynomial) generates vector of polynomials (vector of vectors of doubles). Then, I use this function in other function, it looks like this:

```
vector < vector <double> > lancuch_sturma ( vector <double> wielomian ) 
{
        /* some code here */
}
```

Next I have function that uses `lancuch_sturma`:

```
unsigned int ilosc_zmian_znaku (double x, vector < vector <double> > lancuch_sturma)
{
    if (lancuch_sturma.size() == 0)
        return 0;
    else 
    {
        /* some code here */
    }   
}
```

After that I have in `main()` a `vector <double> wielomian` filled with doubles. When I try to use it:

```
unsigned int test = ilosc_zmian_znaku (-2, lancuch_sturma(wielomian));
```

I get familiar error:

> ---
>
> ### Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
>
> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP110D.dll File: c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector Line: 1140
>
> Expression: vector subscript out of range
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

I get this error in  `ilosc_zmian_znaku`, in line where `if (lancuch_sturma.size() == 0)` is located, but I don't know what possibly gives that error. I put breakpoint there and I have my `lancuch_sturma` with `size=7`. To be exact:

```
-       lancuch_sturma  { size=7 }  std::vector<std::vector<double,std::allocator<double> >,std::allocator<std::vector<double,std::allocator<double> > > >
```

If `lancuch_sturma` have `size=7` then why I get error while checking if this size is `==0` ?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure, that the error comes from `(lancuch_sturma.size() == 0)` line? Because it looks, like it's comming from `some more code here` part. Do you debug in the debug mode? When debugging in the Release mode, the "current" line presented by the debugger is not very reliant. Also passing vector by value might not be the best idea, but it is no incorrect per-se.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, it is not there. The thing is that I placed breakpoint that never happens and program crashes in the place I really try to gain access from out of vector. I feel kinda ashamed now, I think the question is "answered" or can be deleted, not sure what should be done here.

Comment: You pass and return the vector by value.  That means each call to your function is operating on a different, and temporary, vector.  I would guess you want to use references.

Comment: In this case all I really need is integer number that I get using function that uses function that uses.. etc. I don't really need to access or remember this vector later and temporary copy is ok for me (or at least I hope so ;P )

Comment: I agree with @luk32 `lancuch_struma.size()` since `std::vector::size` is `noexcept` the exception couldn't be thrown by `size`. My guess is that you are messing the subscripts of your vectors somewhere else. Furthermore, passing `std::vector` and even more `std::vector<std::vector>` by value is extremely inefficient.

Comment: How should I pass it then? I'm kinda beginner in C++ and still learning.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Returning a `std::vector` by value is OK from C++11 and beyond, because `std::vector` has move constructors.

Comment: You should pass them by reference (e.g., `signed int ilosc_zmian_znaku (double x, vector < vector <double> > const &lancuch_sturma))`.

Comment: @40two The fact that they can be moved addresses a possible efficiency concern, but doesn't make that return value any less temporary when it isn't assigned to anything.

Comment: I usually used references while passing vectors when I wanted to change something inside vector. While using vector just as a function inside other function, only to generate some values that I use afterwards, I was using it without references. Why it is inefficient? And why should I put `const` before reference? Won't it prevent me from modifying my temporary vector?

Comment: @RetiredNinja hmmm, you are suggesting that in the case "isn't assigned to anything" (i.e., dead call of the function, we don't need anything to be returned) creating an empty `std::vector` as dummy just to pass it to the function is better?

Comment: @40two No, I'm suggesting, in this particular case where we do not really have enough code to determine the exact problem, that the by value return of the vector may be an issue.  It is very common to see debug assertions such as this because a temporary was used beyond its lifetime, or because the function returning the copy was used like `for(auto it = foo().begin(); it != foo().end(); ++it)` making the iterators point to different containers.

Comment: Didn't thought about this situation, thank you.